# Disable Maximize Button c++ console application

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, windows-7

I am maintaining old C++ application running console. I has disabled "close" buttun . I need to disable maximize button as well. The following code disabes the close button

```
DeleteMenu(GetSystemMenu(GetConsoleWindow(), FALSE), SC_CLOSE, MF_BYCOMMAND);
DrawMenuBar(GetConsoleWindow());
```

I have added line to disable maximize button:

```
DeleteMenu(GetSystemMenu(GetConsoleWindow(), FALSE), SC_CLOSE, MF_BYCOMMAND);
DeleteMenu(GetSystemMenu(GetConsoleWindow(), FALSE), SC_MAXIMIZE, MF_BYCOMMAND);
DrawMenuBar(GetConsoleWindow());
```

It works, the button is disabled but it is not greyed out. (The Close button is greyed out)
What am I missing?
Thank you.

Comment: The console window chrome is not really something you should mess around with IMHO. People can still kill your program with Ctrl+Break.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`SetWindowLong`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633591(v=vs.85).aspx) to change the window style, then call `SetWindowPos`. Example:

```
HWND hwnd = GetConsoleWindow();
DWORD style = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE);
style &= ~WS_MAXIMIZEBOX;
SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, style);
SetWindowPos(hwnd, NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE|SWP_NOMOVE|SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for for both answers. The disabling worked. You are absolutely correct - Ctrl-Break still kills the program. Disabling of the button just prevents from doing it accidentally.